# Session fixation in Java

Tags: java, session-management, session-fixation

In the process of developing a vulnerable jsp/servlet based application I made an attempt to introduce the session fixation vulnerability.

Referring to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession(boolean)) I came up with the following code which when used in the servlet to create a new session, should return the existing HTTP session if it exists and otherwise it should return null. In any case a new session should not be created.

```
if(obj.checkLogin(username, password))//if credentials are valid
    {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);//return the existing session

    if(session != null)
            response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp");
        else
            response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
    }
```

In order to test the code I deployed it using tomcat 7 and tested for session fixation:

1. Observe the cookie (`c1`) when login page loads (using an intercepting proxy)
2. Enter the correct credentials in the login form.  The authentication was successful and I was redirected to LoginSuccess.jsp
3. Observe the cookie (`c2`) after the authentication.

I found the cookies `c1` and `c2` to be different. Which implies that the code is not vulnerable to session fixation.  I am having trouble understanding this behavior. Why is it that the original cookie `c1` does not persist after the authentication?

Comment: I think we need to see the implementation of `obj.checkLogin(username, password)` to answer this. This must be where the session is created as the `getSession(false)` in your posted code does not create sessions.

Comment: @SilverlightFox the checkLogin() method just checks the entered credentials against a hard-coded list. As this was an experiment I know that the session management is done by the above code only.

Comment: In your exercise can you confirm that `c1` was server generated, referring to an existing active session?

Comment: @Shurmajee Can you please share your github source code link?

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy It has been a long time man. No idea where the code is now. I never put it on Github

Answer (score -1):

The servlet engine you are using securely handles session cookies when you call request.getSession(), and is not vulnerable to fixation.

(as discussed in the comments) This behavior is both intentional and correct. Whether getSession(), getSession(true) or getSession(false) is called, the server relies on its own memory to determine if there is a valid session matching the value received from the client. If there is no such session in server memory, then the servlet engine ignores the session id from the client. This prevents session fixation, since the server never allows the client to define the sessionid of a new session (new from the perspective of the server that doesn't have that sessionid in memory.)

You either need to find an older, broken servlet engine that is vulnerable to session fixation or you need to replace the session management code. If you go with the latter, you will need to determine if you can replace the session generation in place or if you will write your own session management code.

The approach you take should mirror what you are trying to teach. If you want people to teach...

- keep your stuff patched, then go with the broken old engine
- not to write your own session management mechanism, the write your own
- not to modify an existing session management mechanism, then modify the existing one

Comment: The question clearly states that tomcat 7 was used and can you please elaborate your point where you say 'this is typical behavior' ?

Comment: @Shurmajee, you're right, I overlooked that it was tomcat. Will correct that. What is there to elaborate on? "Behaving securely regarding session fixation is typical behavior..." not sure what you're looking to hear... besides, i've removed that bit since it is no longer relevant with the edit.

Comment: The expected behavior in this case would be reuse of the initial cookie after authentication as I am calling the getSession method with a boolean false parameter. There is a difference between getsession() and getSession(false). Please refer to the documentation link given in the question

Comment: @Shurmajee, I am familiar with the documentation. What you expect is broken behavior. Tomcat 7 is not broken in this way, as your testing demonstrates. getSession(false) does not create a session. In your case, no session exists in server memory, so the value received in the request is ignored and no new session is created. This is secure behavior that prevents a servlet developer error from introducing a session fixation flaw. This also makes a lot of sense, as the servlet is not supposed to do session management; the engine is.

Comment: I think there is a slight confusion here. The method getSession(false) does create a new session as a new jsessionid cookie is set after the authentication step (c1 != c2). This behavior is secure but unexpected.

Comment: @Shurmajee you may not have expected the behavior, but it is fully intentional and it *is* the expected behavior. If you think it is truly a bug, go report to Apache that Tomcat should behave insecurely.

Comment: What if the session already exists? Does it generate a new Id and transfer session contents. I mean please could you explain how this prevents session fixation?

Comment: @SilverlightFox, if a session was already created securely, and it's now being used by a different client, that's an entirely different issue.  "why does this prevent session fixation" wasn't really part of the original question - the OP was asking how to cause session fixation, knowing that it was prevented.

Comment: Why do you say it is not vulnerable? You haven't answered the first part of my question.

Comment: @SilverlightFox, I did answer you. Read again. You are bringing up a different topic than session fixation.

Comment: `if a session was already created securely, and it's now being used by a different client` = session fixation.

Comment: @SilverlightFox, no, it's not. Session fixation is not session reuse. It's when the attacker decides the session ID instead of the server. By definition, if the session wä created securely, it's not session fixation, and so you are referencing another issue. If you are truly interested, google it and read up. Or ask a separate question on this site. I'm not going to answer you in comments. That's not what they're for.

Comment: It is when the attacker can set the session id of their victim's session and then ride that session. So by definition it is a valid, server generated session that the id references.